# Why can't I pass this jquery selector in my object script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object, web

Am I missing something with the below code? For some reason, the scripts gotten as far as the 
'buildImgs' function, and then it just throws back undefined results when I attempt to retrieve the dom HTML. Is there a smarter way to run something like this? I'm sort of new to object oriented programming and I have no idea why my '$imgContainer' var isn't passing through. Please help!!!

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var carousel = (function(carousel){

    var config =  {
            mainContainer: $("#container1"),
            $imgContainer: $("#imgcont2"),
            slideDistance: Math.floor(Math.random()*100000001),
            maxWidth: 650,
            maxHeight: 600
    };

    var buildImgs = function(options){
        alert(options.$imgContainer().html());
    }

    var buildWrapper = function(options){
        var $div = options.containerID;
        var $dom = $("#"+$div);
        var html = '<div id="prev'+$div+'" class="btn prev"><img src="http://www.the-leader.com/Global/images/ugc/leftarr_white.png" style="max-width:30%;margin-left:55%;"></div><div id="next'+$div+'" class="btn next"><img src="http://www.the-leader.com/Global/images/ugc/rightarr_white.png" style="max-width:30%;margin-right:55%;"></div><div class="outter-wrap"><div class="inner-wrap'+$div+'" style="height:100%;position:relative;"></div></div>';
        $dom.html(html);
        buildImgs(options);
    }

    var drawContainer = function(options){
        options.mainContainer.html('<div id="'+options.containerID+'"></div>');
        buildWrapper(options);
    }

    carousel.init = function(config) {
        $.extend(config, config);
        config.containerID = Math.floor(Math.random()*100000001);
        drawContainer(config);
    };

    return carousel;    
}(carousel || {}));


</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .indbox{width:100px;height:100px;background-color:#000;}
    .carousel{width:100%;height:100%;margin-top:20px;float:left;background-color:#000;position:relative;}
    .carousel .prev{left:-6%;}
    .carousel .next{right:-6%;}
    .carousel .btn{width:13%;height:13%;position:absolute;top:40%;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;z-index:2;}
    .carousel .outter-wrap{width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;z-index:1}
    .carousel .inner-img-container{vertical-align:middle;display:table-cell;text-align:center;position:relative;}
    .carousel .inner-text-container{width:95.5%;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);color:#FFF;z-index:5;padding:10px;font-size:12px;text-align:left;}
</style>

<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>

    <ul id="imgcont1" style="display:none;">
        <li data-title="Some title goes here1" data-caption="Some type of caption can go in this space" data-img="http://f52e304dfbaee0d644e5-e238cc27b87909affa90e9a9dd352aae.r50.cf1.rackcdn.com/152a8a72-aeed-42a7-99a3-ca4bd0680b55.jpg"></li>

        <li data-title="Some title goes here2" data-caption="Some type of caption can go in this space" data-img="http://familybugs.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/professional-group-of-five-for-web.jpg"></li>

        <li data-title="Some title goes here3" data-caption="Some type of caption can go in this space" data-img="http://groups.ku.edu/~deltasig/images/professional.jpg"></li>

        <li data-title="Some title goes here4" data-caption="Some type of caption can go in this space" data-img="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121103230308/sega/images/6/67/Sonic_Art_Assets_DVD_-_Sonic_The_Hedgehog_-_18.png"></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="imgcont2" style="display:none;">
        <li data-title="Some title goes here1" data-caption="Some type of caption can go in this space" data-img="http://f52e304dfbaee0d644e5-e238cc27b87909affa90e9a9dd352aae.r50.cf1.rackcdn.com/152a8a72-aeed-42a7-99a3-ca4bd0680b55.jpg"></li>

        <li data-title="Some title goes here2" data-caption="Some type of caption can go in this space" data-img="http://familybugs.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/professional-group-of-five-for-web.jpg"></li>

        <li data-title="Some title goes here3" data-caption="Some type of caption can go in this space" data-img="http://groups.ku.edu/~deltasig/images/professional.jpg"></li>

        <li data-title="Some title goes here4" data-caption="Some type of caption can go in this space" data-img="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121103230308/sega/images/6/67/Sonic_Art_Assets_DVD_-_Sonic_The_Hedgehog_-_18.png"></li>
    </ul>

<div class="indbox"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var chris = carousel.init({
        mainContainer: $("#container1"),
        imgContainer: $("#imgcont1"),
        slideDistance: 200,
        maxWidth: 600,
        maxHeight: 400
    });

    var rond = carousel.init({
        mainContainer: $("#container2"),
        imgContainer: $("#imgcont2"),
        slideDistance: 100,
        maxWidth: 600,
        maxHeight: 400
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you should only include snippets illustrating the problem at hand and not all/the majority of your code

Comment: Error messages on the console are probably telling you something like object is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$imgContainer is a variable not a function

Change :

```
var buildImgs = function(options){
    alert(options.$imgContainer().html());
}
```

To

```
var buildImgs = function(options){
    alert(options.$imgContainer.html());
}
```

Also, you are trying to access options array but your init function use a config array.
My guess is that it shoud be

```
var buildImgs = function(options){
    alert(config.$imgContainer.html());
}
```

UPDATE following comment :

Finaly you are using either $imgContainer and imgContainer for the same variable. You should choose a name and stick to it.

Comment: Also, when initializing it, it's called `imgContainer`, then he accesses it with `$imgContainer`

Comment: This was in fact the issue. I've created a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nnb36/

Just fyi, I am kinda new to oop so please don't kill me over the code. If you see somethings that I am doing that either aren't necessary or have better approaches, then please share!

Comment: P.S. I am passing the 'options' as a parameter to the functions in the carousel object. I do this just in case in the future I need to quickly add-to or manipulate the object on the fly.